# How to compute sum, average and product of three numbers using different functions

Tags: c++, function

I need to create a program that accepts 3 numbers and find the sum, average and product. I only need to use **main()**, **get_ABC()**, **compute()** and **display()** functions. I did it right but im not getting the right output about my mathematical operations.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>

float get_A(float A)
{
    cout<<"Enter First Number: ";
    cin>>A;
    return(A);
}

float get_B(float B)
{
    cout<<"Enter Second Number: ";
    cin>>B;
    return(B);
}

float get_C(float C)
{
    cout<<"Enter Third Number: ";
    cin>>C;
    return(C);
}

 float compute_sum(float A,float B,float C)
{
 float sum;

 sum = A + B + C;
 return(sum);

}

float compute_ave(float A,float B,float C)
{
    float ave;
    ave = (A + B + C) / 3;
    return (ave);
}

float compute_prod(float A,float B,float C)
{
    float prod;
    prod = A * B * C;
    return(prod);
}

void display(float sum,float ave,float prod)
{
    cout<<"The sum of three numbers is "<<sum<<".\n";
    cout<<"The average of three numbers is "<<ave<<".\n";
    cout<<"The product of three numbers is "<<prod<<".";
}

float main()
{
    float A,B,C;
    float sum;
    float ave;
    float pro;
    clrscr();
    get_A(A);
    get_B(B);
    get_C(C);
    sum = compute_sum(A,B,C);
    ave = compute_ave(A,B,C);
    pro = compute_prod(A,B,C);
    display(sum,ave,pro);
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

This is the output.

```
Enter First Number: 1
Enter Second Number: 2
Enter Third Number: 3
The sum of three numbers is 0.
The average of three numbers is 0.
The product of three numbers is 0.
```

I really need help. My prof give me this problem without teaching how to code, so i only come up with basics, i really gave up and end up here. You can change, add or replace the codes(with basic codes) if you want and i'll appreciate it.

Comment: "I did it right but im not getting the right output" - one of those two things cannot be true.

Comment: Why are you passing arguments to the `get_*` functions? They don't need it. Instead define the variable locally inside the function. Or better yet, use *one* function which as argument takes the *prompt* to write.

Comment: "My prof give me this problem without teaching how to code" Thats... interesting.

Comment: You need to do A=get_A(A);

Comment: Pop quiz: where is the value being `return`ed from each get function goes?

Comment: And [get a couple of good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read. The header `<iostream.h>` is obsolete. The `main` function returns an `int`. And the values *returned* by the `get_*` functions is discarded (which is your problem!)

Comment: Theyre when you are getting the values... use `A = get_A();` and remove any parameters from the three `get` functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
get_A(A);
get_B(B);
get_C(C);
```

to this:

```
A = get_A(A);
B = get_B(B);
C = get_C(C);
```

so that you use the *return values* of your functions.

Moreover, `main()` should return an `int`, not a `float`.

Furthermore, initialize your variables when you declare them, so that you avoid "is used uninitialized in this function" warnings.

Comment: The `get_*` functions shouldn't take a parameter.

Comment: @tkausl they could just be references